# SQL Server Reporting Services - Authentication issue access web service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, reporting-services

I have an issue where I cannot consume the SSRS web services in my production environment but it works in my local development environment and test environment.  The only difference is the production environment has the web services installed on a different server, our production database server.  However, typing the web service URL into a browser on the production web server correctly prompts for credentials and then loads the web service XML definition when the correct credentials are provided.

The exception I am getting is shown below.

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

I have the following XML in my web.config for accessing the SSRS web services.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="ReportingService2010Soap" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm="54.252.119.210"/>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://xxx/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportingService2010Soap" contract="ReportServer.ReportingService2010Soap" name="ReportingService2010Soap"/>
    <endpoint address="http://xxx/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportingService2010Soap" contract="ReportExecutionServer.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap"/>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I suspect the issue has something to do with the way the production database server is configured, but I have no idea what this could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the reporting services web services weren't configured to use basic authentication.

SSRS authentication configuration: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249(v=sql.105).aspx

SSRS basic authentication configuraiton: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309(v=sql.105).aspx